# Spring xml to java config: how to convert nested xml bean definition

Tags: java, spring, configuration

```
 <bean
    name="ticketValidationFilter"
    class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter"
    p:service="https://my.local.service.com/cas-client">
    <property name="ticketValidator">
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas" />
    </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Can anyone please help to convert this xml definition to java config? Specifically, I am confused about how to declare `ticketValidator`.

```
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean ticketValidationFilter(){

        Filter ticketValidationFilter = new
                org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter();

        FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        frb.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        frb.setFilter(ticketValidationFilter);

        // ticket Validator somewhere here

        Map<String, String> initParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParamMap.put("service", "http://localhost:8889/cas-client");
        frb.setInitParameters(initParamMap);

        return frb;
    }
```

**-----UPDATE FOR FILTERS CONFIG-------**

if you use nested beans for filter configuration(Eg. like in my case), whatever properties you set on your filters - they will be null if you use just setters(don't know why, if anyone eager to explain please do).

To solve this issue: create filter(@Component) that extends GenericFilterBean and set your properties there. Then @Autowire it to your config and use setters on filter registration as usual.**

If you have simple configuration property(eg. String) then you can use Map with init params and set it on the FilterRegistration bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a bean that's used only in this particular external bean, you simply convert it to an instance creation and set the apropriate property.

You can't use `Filter` interface as that doesn't have the setter for ticket validator.

Use `AbstractTicketValidationFilter` instead:

```
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean ticketValidationFilter(){

    AbstractTicketValidationFilter ticketValidationFilter = new
            org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter();

    FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    frb.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    frb.setFilter(ticketValidationFilter);

    //here be ticket validaror

    TicketValidator validator = new org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator("https://localhost:8443/cas");

    ticketValidationFilter.setTicketValidator(validator);

    //end of ticket validator config

    Map<String, String> initParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    initParamMap.put("service", "http://localhost:8889/cas-client");
    frb.setInitParameters(initParamMap);

    return frb;
}
```

The whole beauty of java config is that some complex xml configurations can be converted to very simple java.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Javadoc comment for the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` interface:

> Implementing this interface makes sense for example when an object requires access to a set of collaborating beans.

[@soulcheck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443754/4548231) is appropriate for most use cases, but when you need to register the inner bean with Spring for any reason, like to define init and destroy methods, you need to:

1. Implement `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware`.
2. Store the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` for use inside your `@Bean` method.
3. Use the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` to get access to the `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry` to manually create and register bean definition.
4. Use the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` again to retrieve the bean created in the previous step.

Here's an example skeleton of a class that shows those steps in action:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {
    // members ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // getters and setters ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    // methods ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        ((BeanDefinitionRegistry)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()).registerBeanDefinition(
            "bar",
            BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Bar.class)
                .setInitMethodName("start")
                .setDestroyMethodName("stop")
                .addConstructorArgValue("Hello world!")
                .addPropertyValue("hello", "world")
            .getBeanDefinition()
        );

        final Foo foo = new Foo(applicationContext.getBean("bar", Bar.class));

        return foo;
    }
}
```